# Stack multiple divs on top of each other at the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a section that can have n number of divs at the top then there would be some gap and then n number of divs at the bottom. For the bottom divs i am usign bottom:0 but it overlaps the bottom divs. I have to stack the bottom ones, WITHOUT USING A SEPERATE CONTAINER FOR THEM. Something like this:

```
<section>
   <div> Div Top 1 </div>
   <div> Div Top 2 </div>
   <div> Div Top 3 </div>

   <div> Div Bottom 1 </div>
   <div> Div Bottom 2 </div>
<section>
```

Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Please note that the bottom divs parent should be section but not any other div. I have acheived this containing the bottom ones inside a container but I want to do it keeping the parent of all the divs same due to my other logic.

Comment: are you looping through these n-divs from an array?

Comment: Yes actually it is Angular. But the loops are different. One for top, one for bottom divs

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}

  arr1 = ['Div Top 1', 'Div Top 2', 'Div Top 3'];
  arr2 = ['Div Bottom 1', 'Div Bottom 2', 'Div Bottom 3'];
}
```

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20rem;
}

.my-div {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.top-div.last {
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}

.bottom-div.first {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.my-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0rem;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <section>
    <h6 style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">Using last in ngForOf</h6>
    <div class="my-div top-div" *ngFor="let content of arr1; last as isLast" [ngClass]="{'last': isLast}">
      {{content}}</div>
    <div class="my-div bottom-div" *ngFor="let content of arr2">{{content}}</div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <h6 style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">Using first in ngForOf</h6>
    <div class="my-div top-div" *ngFor="let content of arr1">
      {{content}}</div>
    <div class="my-div bottom-div" *ngFor="let content of arr2; first as isFirst" [ngClass]="{'first': isFirst}">
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <h6 style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">Using a horizontal Rule</h6>
    <div class="my-div top-div" *ngFor="let content of arr1">{{content}}</div>
    <hr class="my-divider">
    <div class="my-div bottom-div" *ngFor="let content of arr2">{{content}}</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[image]

1. You can use the `last` property of `ngFor` to identify the last element of the top array.
2. Add to `ngClass` called `.last` to identify the last element of the `top-div`
3. Then add the `margin-bottom: 10rem` css property

or

1. You can use the `first` property of `ngFor` to identify the first element of the bottom array
2. Add a `ngClass` called `first` to that element.
3. Then add the `margin-top: 10rem` css property

or

1. Add a horizontal rule in between the two(simplest approach)

Comment: About your code: not use `i === arr1.length - 1` or `i === 0`, [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#local-variables) has localvariables, you can use,e.g. `*ngFor="let content of arr1; let i = index;left first=first;left last=last"`.

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, made the changes, your suggested approach is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

We need that the "section" fill all the viewport, for this we use position:fixed and top,left,bottom,rigth to 0

after we use display:flex and flex-direction-column.

```
section{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;

}
```

The last part of the puzzle is use margin-top:auto to the div we can use as separator

```
section div:nth-last-child(3)
{
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-idcpen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

NOTE. you can also "hardcode" using in .html `[style.margin-top]="'auto'"` in the div you want the "division"

```
<section>
   <div> Div Top 1 </div>
   <div> Div Top 2 </div>
   <div> Div Top 3 </div>
   <div [style.margin-top]="'auto'"> Div Bottom 1 </div>
   <div> Div Bottom 2 </div>
<section>
```

**Update** looks like the nth-last-child give "problems" (count wrong), use `nth-last-of-type` instead

```
section div:nth-last-of-type(2)
{
  margin-top:auto;
}
```